# Java: JPQL select statement

Tags: java, orm, select, jpa, jpql

`select x from X x where x.a.id = :a_id` --> Always 0 objects selected

Why does the above JPQL statement not work, but the one below work?

`select a from A a where a.id = :a_id` --> a_obj
`select x from X x where x.a = :a_obj` --> Always correct number of objects selected

Neither query throws an exception during execution, but a different number of results are obtained.

Thanks

---

**Update**

I tried the following queries by using joins:
`select x from X x, x.a a where x.a.id = :a_id` --> TopLink exception for unexpected token

and this:
`select x from X x JOIN x.a a where a.id = :a_id` --> Always correct number of objects selected

With the latter query, I have solved the initial problem at hand. However, now I have got two queries which should work, but for some reason don't.

`select x from X x where x.a.id = :a_id` --> Always 0 objects selected
`select x from X x, x.a a where x.a.id = :a_id` --> TopLink exception for unexpected token

Has anyone else encountered similar behaviour?

Comment: which JPA provider are you using?

Comment: @mdma : TopLink/Java DB, on Glassfish 2.1.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to also bring in entity a in the first example so that it's attributes are visible.

Something like

```
select x from X x join fetch x.a where x.a.id = :a_id
```

(I don't use JPA, I stick to HQL, so this is untested, unproven and comes without a money-back guarantee.)

Comment: @Pascal - Agreed. I wouldn't have expected it to be necessary either, knowing Hibernate. I'm just pushing for another datapoint to see if we can get TopLink to deliver what's expected.

Comment: @Pascal - thanks for the clarification of what you sed - that's gentler wording.

Answer (score 1):

With the following entity for X

```
@Entity
public class EntityX {

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne
    private EntityA a;

    // ...
}
```

And this one for A:

```
@Entity
public class EntityA {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

   //...
}
```

The following JPQL query:

```
from EntityX x where x.a.id = :id
```

Generates the following SQL:

```
select
  entityx0_.id as id282_,
  entityx0_.a_id as a2_282_ 
 from
  EntityX entityx0_ 
 where
  entityx0_.a_id=?
```

It simply works and returns as many results as expected.

Tested with Hibernate (and EclipseLink). If this is not representative of your case, please add more details.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, you have indeed understood my question correctly, however, I am puzzled by the different result I am getting. Could you please point me in the direction of how to see what SQL is generated, like what you have done? (I'm using Toplink/Java DB on Glassfish 2.1.1, with Netbeans IDE, if it makes a difference)

Comment: I don't use TopLink but I think that the `toplink.logging.level.sql` property should do the trick. Have a look at [TopLink JPA Extensions for Logging](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/ias/toplink/JPA/essentials/toplink-jpa-extensions.html#TopLinkLogging) for details.